# Expanded env variable in name of local subdirectory for repo

Tags: git, hudson-plugins

I'm trying to configure a parameterized local subdirectory based on some environmental variables (such as BUILD_ID or BUILD_NUMBER) in Hudson version 3.0.0 with GIT plugin.

When I put something like "code-$BUILD_ID" in the configure page of the job, in the field "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)", visible pressing the Advanced button under "URL repository" field in the Source Code Management section (with GIT selected), the result is that the string is taken as it is, without replacing the text $BUILD_ID with the actual build id.

The same is true with code-${BUILD_ID}.

Is it possible to use parameterized local subdirectory? 
Which is the exact text I need to use?